# Two linear models are not different (F-test) but outcome of regression equations give very diferent values

Tags: r, regression, equation, interaction

I made two models explaining the weight of a plant under four different treatments over time.
One models allows for the intercepts to differ:

```
ancova <- lm(weight ~ time + treatment)
```

and another also allowing the slopes to differ:

```
  mod5 <- lm(weight ~ time + treatment + treatment:time)
```

when i test if these models are significantly different from each other using the anova command:

```
anova(ancova, mod5)
Analysis of Variance Table

Model 1: weight ~ time + treatment
Model 2: weight ~ time + treatment + treatment:time
  Res.Df     RSS Df Sum of Sq      F Pr(>F)
1    115 10392.0                           
2    112  9873.2  3     518.8 1.9617 0.1238
>
```

no significant difference between models can be detected.

However, say i want to predict the weight under treatment B at time == 7 with both models, i get very different outcomes (if i interpret everything right that is).

```
Different slopes Treatment B: y= 8.2*7 - 37.58 = 19.82
Different slopes and intercepts Treatment B: y= (1.31 + 3.80)7 - 27.18 = 8.59
```

The summary tables for both models:

Anova:

```
Call:
lm(formula = weight ~ time + treatment, data = df)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-21.952  -7.674   0.770   6.851  21.514 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -37.5790     3.2897 -11.423  < 2e-16 ***
time          4.7478     0.2541  18.688  < 2e-16 ***
treatmentB    8.2000     2.4545   3.341  0.00113 ** 
treatmentC    5.4633     2.4545   2.226  0.02797 *  
treatmentD   20.3533     2.4545   8.292 2.36e-13 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 9.506 on 115 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.7862,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.7788 
F-statistic: 105.7 on 4 and 115 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

mod5

```
Call:
lm(formula = weight ~ time + treatment + treatment:time, data = df)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-21.281  -7.665   1.611   6.314  26.242 

Coefficients:
                Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)     -27.1785     5.7805  -4.702  7.4e-06 ***
time              3.8023     0.5019   7.576  1.1e-11 ***
treatmentB       -6.1629     8.1749  -0.754   0.4525    
treatmentC       -3.9872     8.1749  -0.488   0.6267    
treatmentD        2.5648     8.1749   0.314   0.7543    
time:treatmentB   1.3057     0.7097   1.840   0.0685 .  
time:treatmentC   0.8591     0.7097   1.210   0.2286    
time:treatmentD   1.6171     0.7097   2.278   0.0246 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 9.389 on 112 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.7969,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.7842 
F-statistic: 62.78 on 7 and 112 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

head of the data:

```
  treatment replicate time weight
1         A         1    6    2.0
2         A         2    6    0.0
3         A         3    6    0.0
4         A         4    6    0.0
5         A         5    6    0.5
6         B         1    6    2.6
```

Can someone explain to me where this differences comes from, or point out where i messed up the formula?

Comment: I don't see any issues here

Comment: Your manual calculations are not correct. I suggest you use the `predict` function.

Comment: In the the model with only main effects, you need to multiply 7 with the time coefficient, 4.7478. Then the predicted weight is 3.8546. For the model with interactions, the predicted is about 2.4. `(-6.1629 + (3.8023+1.3057)*7 - 27.1785)`

Comment: Any errors in your calculations notwithstanding, models can give substantially different predictions even though they might not be 'statistically significantly' different from one another.  Consider last year's nature paper on 'abandoning statistical significance' for a good explanation of this.https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-019-00857-9

Comment: Thanks for all the helpfull comments. Interesting read, the nature article. I did not know that a possible paradigm shift is coming! And thanks Roland for the suggestion on using the predict function, it took some figuring out, but it works now.